# Can't @Autowire a bean into a controller - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring-mvc web app.

The following code has been simplified and sanitised to protect the guilty.  The basic idea is that I have two separate context configuration files: one for MVC, the other for general config stuff.

When Spring goes to wire up the controller, I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.example.ConfigBean com.example.ConfigController.config; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.example.ConfigBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

However, the following code from another servlet works just fine:

```
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());            
ConfigBean config = context.getBean(ConfigBean.class);
```

This suggests to me that the MVC component scanner can't see the config stuff for some reason.  I've tried adding

```
<import resource="config.xml" />
```

to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, but that made no difference.  It feels wrong anyway, as I don't want two instances of the config beans.  Even manually copying the ConfigBean declaration into dispatcher.xml doesn't fix my problem, which suggests to me I'm doing something really dumb.  Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

My detailed configuration is as follows:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

... Some other non-spring stuff ...

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

classpath:config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean class="com.example.ConfigBean">
        <property name="foo" value="bar" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ConfigController.java

```
package com.example;

import com.example.ConfigBean

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/config")
public class ConfigController {

    @Autowired 
    private ConfigBean config;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public @ResponseBody ConfigBean getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
}
```

Comment: The file `/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml` should not be added to `contextConfigLocation` in `context-param`, it will be read by the web-application context

Comment: Oh - wow.  Well, I didn't rule out the possibility of me doing something really dumb :P.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'll post it as a answer

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you have added `/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml` to `contextConfigLocation` in `context-param`.

It is not required as the web-application context will ready the file based on the displater servlet name

From [Spring Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a
>   file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your
>   web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the
>   definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global
>   scope.

Comment: So it turns out this only deferred the error.  +1 anyway, as this (along with gkarmal's answer) helped push me in the right direction.  Will update.

Answer (score 1):

I think the autowiring is failing due to multiple instance of ConfigBean bean being present.  The error message is slightly confusing.  You get the same error if the bean is missing or if there are more than one instance.

The problem is with the component scan in the dispatcher-servlet.xml.  Assuming that the ConfigBean class is also annotated with `@Component` or one of it's subtypes two instances will get created.  Once for the bean definition in config.xml and once by component scanning.

To fix this you need to change the component-scan to ignore non-controller classes.

```
<context:component-scan  user-default-filters='false'>
  <context:include-filter annotation="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

The lookup in the other servlet class is working because you are accessing the root application context directly.

Comment: In this case, ConfigBean is not annotated.  It's just a plain old java class.  +1 anyway, you help push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This did turn out to be pretty dumb.  The `<context:annotation-config />` directive should have been in config.xml, not dispatcher-servlet.xml.

As I understand it, the annotation stuff is in the parent context, so that's where the directive belongs.